# Pseudo code to find number of occurrence of characters in a documents

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata, cloud, amazon-emr, pseudocode

I am trying to write a Pseudo-Code for a MapReduce technique where I need to find the number of occurrence of characters in the document. For example:

`m`: 1000 times, `M`: 5000 times, "": 3000 times, `\n`: 100 times, `.`:20000 times etc.

Can someone please let me know if this is this correct or I can make it better?

I have written the Pseudo-Code as shown below:

```
def Map(documentName, documentContent)
For Character in documentContent
  EmitIntermediate(Character, 1)


def Reduce(Character, Counts)
Char_Count = 0
For count in Counts
   Char_Count += count
Emit(Character,Char_Count)
```

I referred some of the online available Pseudo-Code for map-reduce technique and wrote this one.
For example, they have used to the following Pseudo-Code to find the number of occurrence of the word in a document:

```
def map(documentName, documentContent):
for line in documentContent:
  words = line.split(" ")
  for word in words:
    EmitIntermediate(word, 1)

def reduce(word, counts):
wordCount = 0
for count in counts:
  wordCount += count
Emit(word, wordCount)
```

Comment: Can you please provide me with the line of code where we split by characters instead of Words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Map(documentName, documentContent)
For line in documentContent
  Line_String = line
  For Charcter in Line_String
  EmitIntermediate(Character, 1)


def Reduce(Character, Counts)
Char_Count = 0
For count in Counts
   Char_Count += count
Emit(Character,Char_Count)
```